# Oracle.DataAccess Dll App is not launching

Tags: c#, windows, oracle

I have a WPF c# application using Oracle.DataAccess.dll.
It all works fine on my computer. But when I try to deploy it on a different Windows computer, it throws the following error.

[image]

So what should be done for this? What needs to be installed on the client PC?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest option should be installing Oracle client on the server you are trying to run it from.

Comment: Have you checked if the Oracle you used to develop the app is the same as the one installed in the computer you're trying to deploy to? This happened to me when the app was developed in 64-bit but the recipient computer had a 32-bit installed.

Comment: Well the client PC does not have oracle client. I thought the dll itself is enough. No ?